# Using boost_foreach without const_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, iterator, constants

Is there a way to use boost foreach without defining a `const_iterator`?

My use-case for this is an iterator for a vector, that can contain invalid elements. The iterator should traverse the vector, and yield only the valid elements. It should also repair the vector in the sense that it should swap each invalid item with the next valid item and resize the vector at the end. For example if -1 represents invalid values the vector [6,-1,-1,9,-1,2] should iterate over 6,9 and 2 and leave the vector as [6,9,2].

I tried implementing this with `boost::iterator_facade` but I could not think of a way to implement a `const_iterator`, because the vector can change by removing invalid values and thus cannot be `const`.

Comment: An iterator, by itself, should never _alter_ the list. It's one thing for an algorithm to alter the list. But iterator objects should never do it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm new to C++ and still struggling with some concepts. At the danger of getting off-topic: can you suggest another way of realizing this behavior? I would like to do the repairing during the iteration, so I don't have to loop through them a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of concerns: the container is responsible for its invariants, the iterators for traversal. If you move the repairing to the container you can separate the logical `const` from the `mutable`, hidden parts.

Can you write your iterators the 'dumbest' way possible to disentangle them from the container? For instance storing a numerical index (if it makes sense for your container), then calling a private friend (or more) of the container to access the *logical* n-th element.

The private friend(s) can then be overloaded on `const` and may still modify the `mutable` parts to do the repairing you describe, and then return the element.

---

An (abridged) example of container supporting random-access (and thus numerical indices for access):

```
template<typename T>
class vector {
    mutable std::vector<std::weak_ptr<T>> data; // notice mutable

    T&
    fetch(int n);

    T const&
    fetch(int n) const; // notice const overload

public:
    class const_iterator;
    friend class const_iterator;

    const_iterator
    begin() const;
};

template<typename T>
class vector<T>::const_iterator {
    int index;
    vector<T> const* this_; // notice const
public:
    // constructors go here

    const_iterator&
    operator++()
    { ++index; }
    // ...

    T const&
    operator*() const
    { return this_->fetch(index); } // this will call the const version of fetch
};

// example implementation of the const version of fetch
template<typename T>
T const&
vector<T>::fetch(int n) const
{
    auto removed = std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [](std::weak_ptr<T>& element)
    { return element.expired(); });
    // mutate mutable data member in a logically const member
    data.erase(data.begin(), removed);

    // this assumes that there is no race condition
    // bear with me for the sake of understanding the mutable keyword
    return *data[n].lock();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it could work in my case. Though I didn't understand your last sentence. What do you mean by "overloaded on `const`"? If I define a `const_iterator begin() const {...}` and pass the iterato a reference to `this`, doesn't it have to be a `const` reference?

Comment: @Flogo Indeed. And when the iterator is then e.g. dereferenced with `operator*`, it will defer to this reference (let's name it `this_` and make it a pointer) to call the appropriate `friend` member. Let's say it does `return this_->fetch(current_index);`. It is this particular `fetch` member that should be overloaded on `const`, too.

Comment: so just to be sure I got this right: The container would then contain `Item fetch(int i);` and `Item fetch(int i) const;`?
If so, how would the `const` version work? Just skipping over invalid entries without compacting the vector?

Comment: @Flogo the `mutable` keyword can help separate the logical `const` part from whatever machinery is needed to maintain class invariants, even in the face of `const`. Does my example help?

Comment: Thanks for the example, I didn't know the `mutable` keyword.

Comment: Isn't this going to traverse the whole container each time you access an item in the hope of removing something? That could be disaster for performance?

Comment: @UncleBens It's an illustration. There is no performance to consider, it's imaginary. There are no performance requirements. It's smoke and mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

All forms of "foreach" are specifically for iterating over every element of a container. You are not *just* iterating over every element of a container. You are *modifying* the container as you iterate.

So just write a regular for-loop. There's no need for special cleverness or anything.

---

Here's the code for it:

```
std::vector<int> it = vec.begin();
for(; it != vec.end;)
{
  if(*it < 0)
  {
    it = vec.erase(it);
    continue;
  }
  else
  {
    //Do stuff with `it`.
    ++it;
  }
}
```

See, just a simple loop. No need for fancy iterator facades or other such gimmickry.

Comment: I do need some kind of cleverness to remove the invalid entries. I want to remove them during the iteration, so the next iteration over the set will be faster. But, yeah, I see the problem with foreach iterating over all elements. I thought of _all elements_ as _all valid elements_ and of _container_ as the logical container instead of the actual vector.

Comment: @Flogo: See my edit. That's what I mean. Oh, and the next iteration won't be faster, since you will constantly be checking to see if any entries are invalid. That check isn't free, even if you usually take it.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, but I was trying to encapsulate this behavior, because I have a lot of places in my code, where I loop over `vec` and didn't want the same code everywhere. I still think the next iteration would be faster, as the vector gets smaller by removing entries, so there will be less checks to validity than before.
Anyway, I believe Luc's answer works for me, and it also separates the modification from the iteration, so the iterator can really be seen as an iterator for the logical container that does not alter its container as you suggested.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This hopefully won't erase items too often. Perhaps it would be a better idea to do the compacting once in a while with the remove-erase idiom and just skip the invalid items in normal loops?